# sum of more than two fields value and return it as new field in solr

Tags: solr

Hi i have multiple docs in my solr having some fields of type integer. i want to summ these fields and return its value in new field. how can i do these. here following is example code.

```
<doc>
    <field type="String" name="name">vinayak</field>
    <field type="int" name="roomRent">1000</field>
    <field type="int" name="electricityBill">500</field>
    <field type="int" name="food">2000</field>
    <field type="int" name="extra">500</field>
</doc>
<doc>
    <field type="String" name="name">sahil</field>
    <field type="int" name="roomRent">1500</field>
    <field type="int" name="electricityBill">700</field>
    <field type="int" name="food">2500</field>
    <field type="int" name="extra">1000</field>
</doc>
```

i want a query which return me as result following...

```
<doc>
    <field type="String" name="name">vinayak</field>
    <field type="int" name="totalCost">4000</field>
</doc>
<doc>
    <field type="String" name="name">sahil</field>
    <field type="int" name="totalCost">5700</field>
</doc>
```

i need query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use fl parameter and add `totalCost` which takes sum of `extra` and `food` values. like below

```
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&fl=name,totalCost:sum(food,extra)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks vinod, its works. i know this bt not know how exact query i create. its help me alot.